# Ограничение ресурсов для запроса

Tags: sql-server, запрос

Добрый день!
Сервер бд находит под нагрузкой (идет частая запись в базу), таблица с данными разделена на секции. При выполнении чтения из любой секции начинает тормозить запись. В связи с этим вопрос, можно ли задать приоритет запросу(выполнение в фоне), либо установить ограничение в ресурсах.

Погуглил и в итоге:
1 приоритет нельзя выставить
2 ограничение в ресурсах - resource governor

Вариант один - организовать запрос большого объема данных, разбивая его на маленькие порции?

Есть ли еще мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: А чтение и запись в одной секции пересекаются, или они в разных секциях происходят? Файлов на файловую группу сколько? _"Есть ли еще мысли по этому поводу?"_ - использовать snapshot изоляцию.

Comment: Запись идёт в другую таблицу, затем данные извлекают из строй таблицы и записываются в секцию. Чтение происходит из другой санкции.

Comment: По-хорошему, конечно, locks/waits помониторить бы на чтении и на записи, чтобы узнать - а что именно там тормозит, блокировки ли это на таблице или её частях, или может быть IO-подсистема плохо отзывается (snapshot её нагрузит дополнительно).

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего запросы на чтение накладывают блокировку. Нужно конечно понимать за какой ресурс идет борьба и от этого плясать. Возможно поможет использование хинтов  типа  NOLOCK  или max dop.

Comment: nolock не прбовали?

Comment: Nolock уже использую. Но все равно уже на средних размерах выборки данных (30000 строк) начинает забирать ресурсы.